# Not able to find Logging option in wso2 management console in WSO2 version 3.0.0

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I am trying to configure logging in WSO2 management console referring to this

https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/Administer/ProductAdministration/Monitoring/Logging/setting-up-logging/. However I can't find the Logging option in the management console. Please find attached email. Do I need to make other change?

I am new to this product, so this might be configuration issue that I might have missed.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/htsiq.png

Comment: Can you let us know what are the logs that you need to configure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Configuring the logging via the carbon console in API Manager is removed from 3.0.0 onwards. (Documentation is in-progress. We will be soon removing the docs related to this.)

You can use the [APIM_HOME]/repository/conf/log4j2.properties file to configure logging and it is hot deployable.